# Elixir not creating multiple css files

Tags: css, laravel, sass, laravel-elixir

Tried to find an awnser to this question but could not find it here?

I'm using Laravel Elixir and got the following in my gulpfile:

```
mix.sass(['app.scss', 'admin.scss'], 'public/css');
```

Can someone tell me why it is not creating two css files but compiles it into one? How can I achieve it creating multiple files?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: try `mix.sass('app.scss').sass('admin.scss')` This should compile into two files.

Comment: That didn't work for me. The documentation also states that  the sass method can be only called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to mix sass files is (https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/ingredients/sass.js):

```
/**
 * Prepare the Sass task.
 *
 * @param {string|array}  src
 * @param {string}        output
 * @param {object|null}   options
 * @param {bool}          useRuby
 */
var addSassTask = function(src, output, options, useRuby) {
    return compile({
        compiler: 'Sass',
        plugin: useRuby ? 'gulp-ruby-sass' : 'sass',
        pluginOptions: buildOptions(options, useRuby),
        src: src,
        output: output || elixir.config.cssOutput,
        search: '**/*.+(sass|scss)'
    });
};
```

You have,

```
mix.sass(['app.scss', 'admin.scss'], 'public/css');
```

Here, `src = ['app.scss', 'admin.scss']`

and `output = 'public/css'`

So you should combine a single file to the same file as output as :

```
mix.sass('app.scss', 'app.scss');
mix.sass('admin.scss', 'admin.scss');
```

Comment: That didn't work but got me on the right track.

I got it to work eventualy, specifing the output file completely:

    mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/css/app.css').sass('admin.scss', 'public/css/admin.css'); Maybe you can add this in your awnser? or should i create an awnser myself for this?

Answer (score 3):

yes the provided code almost did the trick, i wrote it a bit different though...

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix
    .sass('app.scss', './public/css/app.css')
    .sass('admin.scss', './public/css/admin.css');
});
```

but this atleast for me, didnt work till i started the normal gulp task, gulp watch wont create the new files :S

so stop watch and start the default gulp task with "gulp", after the files are created gulp watch will work again

Comment: Just restarting gulp watch did not work? I know you should always restart the 'gulp watch' command after you've made changes to your gulpfile, but i don't see what running just 'gulp' does differently.

Comment: nope only restarting the watch task not created the files, i don't know why. I'm using gulp mainly from a yeoman generator, or by installing it with bower or something, first time using it elixir.